# How to get the type of the bluetooth device connected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bluetooth

I am getting bluetooth device connected. Trying to get the device type.

```
val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [BluetoothClass](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass)

> Represents a Bluetooth class, which describes general characteristics and capabilities of a device. For example, a Bluetooth class will specify the general device type such as a phone, a computer, or headset, and whether it's capable of services such as audio or telephony.

With [`getBluetoothClass()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#getbluetoothclass) you should be able to retrieve this type of informations.
Remember the permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```